# Can IMAP settings delete emails from a previously configured POP mail profile?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, imap

I have a friend that recently "migrated" her inbox from one hosting company to another.  The new hosting company advised her of the details to reconfigure settings in Outlook, so i took the IMAP details and configured these in Outlook.  However, as soon as I had successfully logged her in & sync'd using send & receive - all of her sub-folders disappeared!

Are these still in the Outlook profile? or have these been removed for good?

Answer (score 0):

The PST file should have been backed up.

If you used the same main folder names and sync'd from a basically new IMAP setup, then I think the sub-folders have gone for good.

Check the IMAP Web Mail to be certain to see if the folders went to another location within IMAP but I don't think so.

Comment: In hindsight, yeah backing up the PST file would've been a good idea, but i've never come across this issue before.  Funny thing is - when accessing the webmail inbox I could've sworn there were tons of emails in there & then all gone with the exception of some recent ones.  Is there no way I can just start from scratch with the old profile though (ie. C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook) ?  Or is this profile now the new profile?

Comment: The profile is not a PST file - just the account structure. You can look there and see if there is an older PST file but not likely.

Comment: Agree, seems that you could restore those email only if you could find the old PST file.